# Key column 'courseid' doesn't exist in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `course` with the columns

```
courseid
coursename
```

and I have the table `subject` with the columns

```
sub_id
sub_name
```

and I want to define a foreign key on my subject table.

This is my SQL code

```
ALTER TABLE subject 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (courseid) 
REFERENCES course(courseid);
```

And this is the error I get:

> Key column 'courseid' doesn't exist in table**

Comment: Is `courseid` a key in table `course`?

Answer (score 1):

First add `courseid` column in the `subject` table

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE subject
ADD courseid varchar(100);

ALTER TABLE subject
ADD FOREIGN KEY (courseid)
REFERENCES course (courseid);
```

Comment: yeah I add the column then i try the code again... i have this error  `Cannot add foreign key constraint`

Comment: Do you know which MySQL DB engine are you using? Foreign Keys are only supported in InnoDB. Try running `SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'subject'` and see if it returns an `engine` column

Comment: Make sure that the new column added into the `subject` table has the same data type as in the `course` table

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE subject ADD FOREIGN KEY (courseid) 
REFERENCES course (courseid) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Make sure that both of ur table structure are in innodb and relational fields are  are indexed

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

**EDITED**

```
ALTER TABLE subject ADD courseid varchar(10);
ALTER TABLE subject ADD Constraint 
FOREIGN KEY(courseid) REFERENCES course(courseid);
```

Please change the datatype and its length depends on the primary key's.

Comment: i have error like this... `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES course(courseid)' at line 3`

Comment: @JeraldPunx change the datatype and its length as the primary key's exactly.